# Axios API Search function is returning everything

Tags: reactjs, axios

Currently trying to create a search function that returns a set of results.  I am using axios to try and set the query in prefix.  However, all it's doing is returning all articles.  No matter what input or the query is.  Is there something I am missing in my api call?  Should I instead use an inline statement instead?  Maybe I should drop axios?  I don't know.  Here is my code:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Suggestions from '../components/Suggestions'

const { API_KEY } = process.env
const API_URL = 'http://djangoandreact.herokuapp.com/api/'

class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    query: '',
    results: []
  }

  getInfo = () => {
    axios.get(`${API_URL}?api_key=${API_KEY}&prefix=${this.state.query}&limit=7`)
      .then(({ data }) => {
          console.log(data)
        this.setState({
          results: data
        })
      })
  }

  handleInputChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      query: this.search.value
    }, () => {
      if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
        if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
          this.getInfo()
        }
      } else if (!this.state.query) {
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          placeholder="Search for..."
          ref={input => this.search = input}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <Suggestions results={this.state.results} />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default Search
```

Comment: What API are you using? Are you sure `prefix` is the correct query parameter name?

Comment: I'm using a django back end.  I thought prefix worked for everything!

Answer (score 0):

In my Opinion, ".then" need to res. It means, "response".

```
axios.get('')
.then(res => console.log(res.data))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

if you try this, you can find the data from API

Comment: Gives the same response.  Must be something with the backend

Comment: getInfo = () => {
    axios.get(`${API_URL}?api_key=${API_KEY}&prefix=${this.state.query}&limit=7`)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        .then(this.setState({
            results: data
        })
        ).catch(err => {throw(err)})